# Why does passing a C-style string to a function result in not being able to access the string?

Tags: c++, tree, c-strings

I have this code here below, which describes a structure called Node which contains a pointer to an Entry type and two pointers to other Nodes. It is a tree.

```
struct Node {
public:
    Entry* value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    Node() {
        this->value = new Entry();
        this->left = nullptr;
        this->right = nullptr;
    }
    Node(Entry* init_value) {
        this->value = init_value;
        this->left = nullptr;
        this->right = nullptr;
    }

    int insert(Entry* e)
    {
        if(this->value->key == nullptr) {
            this->value = e;
            this->left = new Node();
            this->right = new Node();
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            if(this->value->compare(e) > 0) {
                return this->left->insert(e);
            }
            else if(this->value->compare(e) < 0) {
                return this->right->insert(e);
            }
            else {
                return -1; // error code
            }
        }
    }

    int research(char* key)
    {
        if(key == nullptr) { return -1; }

        if(this->value->key == nullptr) { return -1; }

        if(strcmp(this->value->key, key) > 0) {
            return this->right->research(key);
        }
        else if(strcmp(this->value->key, key) < 0) {
            return this->left->research(key);
        }
        else {
            return this->value->id;
        }
    }
};
```

Then I have a function in which, after ensuring that the variable key (which is a char*, ie a C-style string) is not a nullptr, I call reasearch on a Node like this:

```
int result = root->reasearch(key);
```

Why cannot I access the string inside the function, having a segmentation fault?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you probably mean `const char*`

Comment: What did the debugger tell you? When you step into the function, do both `this->value->key` and `key` have valid addresses? do those addresses contain the strings you think they should contain? is it making it to that function, or is it trying to dereference a null node and/or entry pointer at some point?

Comment: Here is my entire code: https://github.com/ixplog/Graph-project (I now that it is not minimal, but I already tried to be minimal in the code above; probably it was excessive minimality)

Comment: "Minimal" doesn't mean to just show a minimal portion of your code. It means trimming your code of all the things that are unnecessary to reproduce the problem, all while keeping the code compilable. This requires work on your part, which is why so many posters don't do it.

Answer (score 4):

In your tree search `research()` you will go down in the tree until either you find a matching node, or you reach a leaf.

Unfortunately, you assume that the right and left node are always non null, hence you'll end up trying to dereference a null pointer.

**More details:**

Suppose in the tree there is ony one node, with the key "ABC++".  The node will look like:

```
this->value->key points to "ABC++"
this->left is nullptr
this->right is nullptr
```

when you then call `research("AAA")` the step by step execution will be:

```
    if(key == nullptr)              // condition is false 
        { ... }                     // skipped

    if(this->value->key == nullptr) // condition is false
       { ... }                      // skipped

    if(strcmp(this->value->key, key) > 0) {  // condition is true 
        return this->right->research(key);  // OUCH!!! SEGFAULT 
    ...
```

The problem is that in this example `this->right` is `nullptr` and dereferencing it with `->research` is  UB.

**How to solve it:**

```
int research(char* key)
{
    if(key == nullptr) { return -1; }

    if(this->value==nullptr || this->value->key == nullptr)  // better verify that non null.
       { return -1; }  

    if(strcmp(this->value->key, key) > 0) {
        return this->right ? this->right->research(key) : -1 ;  // check for nullptr
    }
    else if(strcmp(this->value->key, key) < 0) {
        return this->left ? this->left->research(key) : -1;   // check for nullptr
    }
    else {
        return this->value->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're right and so I changed the code as you told me! Thanks! However my problem is that I cannot access the key: I have tried to print it in the first line of code of the function and I have a segmentation fault; are you aware of some common mistakes regarding C-style strings and passing them into functions?

Comment: Try to first print `(void*)this` to be sure to work on a valid object, then verify that your key is not null.  If necessary, open a new question for the new problem, with updated code.